# SMTP Pro test mail error

Tags: magento-1.9, smtp

I just enabled the smtp pro module and Go to configuration->SMTP pro option
and click the 
`Run Self Test` in logging and Debugging i got following error.

[image]

can you please help..

Answer (score 1):

You must allow the sending emails via the applications & security section of your webmail interface.

Comment: What is mean : Template: queued email?

Comment: Where did you found that @Rathinam

Comment: Here is the screenshot : https://imgur.com/CQvCivQ